# Expand a vector and count instances

Tags: r

I have a data.frame

```
orig.DF<-data.frame(V1=c("A", "B", "C"), V2=c(3,2,4))
```

and I have to expand it so that it takes the following form

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 2
C 3
C 4
```

I tried `taaply` and `ave` but I can't get it to count to `1:x` and repeat the `V1` accordingly

Comment: Do the answers lack something?

Comment: No. Thank you for reminding me. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), V2 = c(3, 2, 4))
data.frame(x = rep(df$V1, df$V2), y = sequence(df$V2))
  x y
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 A 3
4 B 1
5 B 2
6 C 1
7 C 2
8 C 3
9 C 4
```

Comment: Very cute, especially the `sequence` part!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
do.call(
   rbind, 
   apply(orig.DF, 1, function(row) expand.grid(row["V1"], 1:row["V2"]))
)
```